# Deny messages access to Telegram Bot in a group where it's an admin

Tags: admin, telegram, telegram-bot, administrator, telegram-api

Reading telegram documentation about [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) and [what messages a bot will receive](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) it seems there is no way to deny access to messages to a bot which is a group administrator.

My bot need to be an admin in order to pin messages, but I would like to get access only to bot commands, replies to bot messages, and so on, like a non-admin bot with privacy mode enabled.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the group chat then it's possible. Add a bot to the group chat and enable the pin messages option in the restrictions for the bot user. It doesn't have to be an admin.

If you want to handle the Notifications channel then it's not possible as bots in that channel have to be admins.